# Connection phonegap/cordova

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I took this model of the Phonegap site and yet he does not issue an alert showing the connection status. 
I want to open the InAppBrowser I'm creating it if it shows an internet connected via 3g or wifi and if not it will issue an alert warning the user.

Example: [Example Connection Phonegap site](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection_accessing_the_feature)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>navigator.connection.type Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        checkConnection();
    }

        function checkConnection() {
            var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

            var states = {};
            states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
            states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
            states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
            states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

            alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
        }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>A dialog box will report the network state.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post at least your code please ?

Comment: Clem, The code this just the way this ai this link, I have not changed one punctuation.

Comment: Have you added the plugin in your project ?

Comment: Yes,  <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager" />

Comment: i mean `cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-network-information.git` then `cordova build`. And how do you test it ?